# jQuery cannot add class to dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I know that if I add content dynamically I have to use an event handler for a parent element using on(). But when I use addClass on dynamically added content the class immediately disappears.

Here's the relevant part of HTML (just to make sure I don't missed typos):

```
<div id="training_management_categories_items">
    <ul style="list-style: none; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding:0px;" id="training_management_categories_items_ul">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the code that adds the dynamic elements:

```
function GetCategories()
{
  var url = './ajax/training_management_data.php';
  $('#training_management_categories_items').html('<ul style="list-style: none; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding:0px;" id="training_management_categories_items_ul"></ul>');
  $('#training_management_categories_items_ul').append(' \
    <li class="training_management_categories_list"> \
      <a href="" class="training_management_categories_list_a" id="training_management_categories_list_a_all">All</a> \
    </li> \
  ');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=get_categories",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, data) {
        $('#training_management_categories_items_ul').append(' \
          <li class="training_management_categories_list"> \
            <a href="" class="training_management_categories_list_a" id="training_management_categories_list_a_'+data.id+'">'+data.name+'</a> \
          </li> \
        ');     
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    GetCategories();
});
```

But when I click the element the class is added for just like 0.1 seconds (had to switch the `background-color` for `.categories_selected` to red to see it) and I don't get why.

```
$('#training_management_categories_items').on('click', '.training_management_categories_list_a', function () {
    $(this).addClass('categories_selected'); // DOESN'T WORK
    alert( $( this ).text() ); // THIS WORKS
});
```

So if I click on one of the dynamically created elements it shows the text (for example "All" which is not fetched from php but you get the idea) but doesn't permanently add the class.

And just for me making ABSOLUTE sure I didn't miss anything really really stupid, here's the CSS:

```
a.training_management_categories_list_a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-image:url("img/icons/folder.png");
    background-size:16px 16px;
    padding-left:25px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-size:9pt;
    background-position:4px 2px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:2px;
}

a.training_management_categories_list_a:hover {
    background-color:#aaa;
}

a#training_management_categories_list_a_all {
    font-weight:bold;
}

a.categories_selected {
    background-color:#aaa !important;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Edit: using jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: you have to prevent the default action else the page will get reloaded...so either `return false` from the event handler or call `event.preventDefault()` after receiving the `event` parameter in the handler

Comment: I think the `:hover` style gets in the way.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh man... yes you're right of course. I was near to going mad. Thanks! Why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: lol I missed that, the anchor element reloads the page haha

Comment: just updated my answer for people to know what was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, I tried out that in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/n42m6gpf/1/

What is happening is that the color you are setting in the `a.categories_selected` is the same color it was before (in the hover), I changed it to yellow `background-color: yellow !important;` so you realize it is working. Try clicking the link and you will see how it changes the background color before the alert pops up.

UPDATE: Just for people looking for answers to know. Anchor element reloads the page so styles will be set to the initial ones. You are using ajax so you don't want the page to be reloaded, therefore you should pass an `e` parameter to your function and use `e.preventDefault()` on your `onClick` function to avoid the default behaviour of anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you, change this line:

```
$(this).addClass('categories_selected'); // DOESN'T WORK
```

to this one:

```
$(this).parent().find('.training_management_categories_list_a').addClass('categories_selected');
```

I don't know why but I have seen this problem before and solved with this way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inspecting the element to see if the class is present? That usually helps me identify what's going wrong. It might be that another class is overriding the properties from your class...?

Comment: Nah, even in your fiddle the problem persists. After clicking the ok button the yellow color gets removed again. The solution is in Arun P Johny's comment.