# Adding Class to Dynamically added textbox

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to .addClass to a dynamically added element.

My Code is:

```
$("#element").prop('disabled', true).addClass('mydisabled');
```

the element is getting disabled which is required but the style declared in 'mydisabled is not taking effect.

The Style is also very simple

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mydisabled {
    background-color:#e0dede;
  }
</style>
```

Any help/idea what I am missing ?

Comment: Try like this **if($("#element").prop('disabled', true)){$(this).addClass('mydisabled');}**

Comment: your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qga33gjf/

Comment: you are disabling this element on some click event or by-default

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef  he says that it's dynamically added element

Comment: @AlivetoDie even its dynamically ..this code should work fine https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qga33gjf/1/

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef I see your jsfiddle how ever same code not working with me I thought there is some confilict with style in my current project

Comment: @AliAdnan I heard its a bad way to use `!important` but give it a try `background-color:#e0dede !important;` if it works so the problem comes from here

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef just see your comment :) and I am glad your suggestion did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a class with a property that already defined in another class of that element. Thats why `!Important` works here.

If you want to change only one property with jQ, try use css():
`$("#element").prop('disabled', true).css('background-color', 'eee');`

Or remove other class with background color and add mydisabled.

Also can remove all classes and replace them with others:

`$("#element").prop('disabled', true).attr('class', 'mydisabled');` - so all classes will be replaced by "mydisabled" class

Comment: I tried both your suggestion `$("#element").prop('disabled', true).attr('class', 'mydisabled');` // not worked  `.css('background-color', 'eee');` // this Worked Thanks

Comment: Ok, thats strange. I would inspect this behaviour a bit more. Might be some problems with css source

Answer (score -1):

After much googling I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436798/jquery-cannot-add-class-to-dynamically-added-content) a trick which solve my problem that is
adding  !important  is did the trick
Thanks you all of you sor your support

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mydisabled {
    background-color:#e0dede !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Dont use important. Instead increase its specificity.